# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) - CV2

Tags: python, windows, model, yolo, opencv

I'm trying to introduce bounding boxes in CV2 for realtime recognition, but when I put attributes in the for loop, the error happens: "ValueError: not enough values ​​to unpack (expected 3, got 1) ". The data I'm using are the weights of a model I trained from YOLOV8.The code in question is:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO (f'best.pt')

# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
COLORS = [(0, 255, 25, (255, 255, 0), (0,255,0), (255, 0, 0))]
class_names=[]
while(True):
      
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    #results = model.predict(frame, conf=0.25)

    #print(results)

    classes, scores, boxes = model.predict(frame, conf=0.25)

    for (classid, score, box) in zip(classes, scores, boxes):
        color = COLORS[int(classid) % len(COLORS)]

        label = f"{class_names[classid[0]]} : {score}"

        cv2.rectangle(frame, box, color, 2)


    #if len(classIds) > 0:
        #for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), results):
            #qcv2.rectangle(frame, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
  
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      
    # the 'q' button is set as the
    # quitting button you may use any
    # desired button of your choice
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
  
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where exactly is the error occurring? Could you provide the full traceback? Also, should COLOR really be a list containing a single tuple with three integers and three nested tuples?

Answer (score 0):

The variable "boxes" returned by the model.predict() contains only one value, but the "zip" function in the for loop expects three .Try

```
for (box,) in boxes:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, box, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```